# Error 404 Not Found. Why is my RestController not recognized from Spring Boot Application?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa

I have the following problem. I have a simple Spring Boot Application that is supposed to process the debts of users. The service does compile, but neither a PostRequest to insert a new record nor a GetRequest to display the debt of a user works. When the service is started, the application automatically creates the appropriate table for the entity. Therefore I assume that the database connection will not be the problem. It looks like my service does not recognize the RestController. With Postman I keep getting the error code "404 Not Found".

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

My Entity

```
package Entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;

@Entity
@Table(name= "debts")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class DebtsEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private String userId;
    @Column(name = "invoice_id")
    private int invoiceId ;
    @Column(name = "creditor")
    private String creditor;
    @Column(name = "amount")
    private double amount;
    @Column(name = "deadline")
    private String deadline;
    @Column(name = "installment")
    private double installment;
    
    
    public DebtsEntity(){
        
    }

    

    public DebtsEntity(int id, String userId, int invoiceId, String creditor, double amount, String deadline,
            double installment) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.userId = userId;
        this.invoiceId = invoiceId;
        this.creditor = creditor;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.deadline = deadline;
        this.installment = installment;
    }


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }


    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }


    public int getInvoiceId() {
        return invoiceId;
    }


    public void setInvoiceId(int invoiceId) {
        this.invoiceId = invoiceId;
    }


    public String getCreditor() {
        return creditor;
    }


    public void setCreditor(String creditor) {
        this.creditor = creditor;
    }


    public double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }


    public void setAmount(double amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }


    public String getDeadline() {
        return deadline;
    }


    public void setDeadline(String deadline) {
        this.deadline = deadline;
    }


    public double getInstallment() {
        return installment;
    }


    public void setInstallment(double installment) {
        this.installment = installment;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "debtsEntity [id=" + id + ", userId=" + userId + ", invoiceId=" + invoiceId + ", creditor=" + creditor
                + ", amount=" + amount + ", deadline=" + deadline + ", installment=" + installment + "]";
    }
    
}
```

My RestController

```
package Controller;

import java.net.URI;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder;

import DAO.DebtsDAO;
import Entity.DebtsEntity;

@RestController
public class DebtsController {

    @Autowired
    DebtsDAO debtsDAO;
    
    @GetMapping("/{userId}/debts")
    public List<DebtsEntity> retrieveDebtsByUserId(@PathVariable String userId)
    {
        List<DebtsEntity> debts = debtsDAO.findByUserId(userId);
        
        return debts;
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/debts")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> createInvoice(@RequestBody DebtsEntity debtsEntity)  
    {  
        DebtsEntity savedUser =debtsDAO.save(debtsEntity);
        URI location= ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest()
        .path("path/{id}")
        .buildAndExpand(savedUser.getId()).toUri();
        
        return ResponseEntity.created(location).build();
    }  
}
```

My DAO

```
package DAO;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import Entity.DebtsEntity;

@Component
public interface DebtsDAO extends JpaRepository<DebtsEntity, Integer>{

    List<DebtsEntity> findByUserId(String user_id);

}
```

My application.properties

```
## Database konfiguration
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Test
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
# define if Database Queries should be written in logfile
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=public
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL81Dialect

server.port=8000
spring.application.name=Debts
```

My dependencies

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>LifeOps</groupId>
    <artifactId>Service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Service</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

UPDATE 1

Get-Request

URL: http://localhost:8000/1000/depts

PostRequest

URL: http://localhost:8000/depts
RequestBody:

```
{
    "id":1000,
    "user_id": "ABC1234",
    "invoice_id":100001,
    "creator": "A12L",
    "amount": 123012.56,
    "deadline": "20.10.12",
    "installment": 50.00
}
```

```
package Service;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;

@EntityScan(basePackages = "entity")
@SpringBootApplication
public class ServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

UPDATE 2

[image]

```
Class                                 package
DebtsApplication                      service.debts
DebtsController                       service.debts.controller
DebtsEntity                           service.debts.entity
DebtsDAO                              service.debts.dao
```

Comment: Why did you ommit very important thing which is the url that you are calling?

Comment: Sry u are right i forgot it. It Updatet the URLs for this case

Comment: Can you also add your main class?

Comment: now its Updatet too

Comment: Does it have no package?

Comment: the main class have an separat package that called Service

Comment: That is the issue. Check my answer below.

Comment: Where is `ServiceApplication` application? It is nowhere to be found.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you add a base package (something like "com.doncarlito") and put `ServiceApplication` in it.

```java
package com.doncarlito;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;

@EntityScan(basePackages = "entity")
@SpringBootApplication
public class ServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Then move all the other existent packages to be sub-packages of this one:

- com.doncarlito.entity
- com.doncarlito.dao
- com.doncarlito.controller
- com.doncarlito.service

The reason being that `@SpringBootApplication` encapsulates `@Configuration`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, and `@ComponentScan` annotations with their default attributes. The default value for `@ComponentScan` means that all the sub-packages on the package the `@ComponentScan` is used are scanned. That is why it is usually a good practice to include the main class in the base package of the project.

Comment: I have tried the solution. In UPDATE 2 my folder hierarchy is shown. However, I now get errors when compiling. Now the compiler cant creating the bean.  Error creating bean with name 'debtsController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'debtsDAO';

Comment: That is in fact weird, but can we try a couple of things? 1. Remove `@EnableAutoConfiguration` from `DebtsEntity` as it is unnecessary as explained above. 2. Replace `@Component` with `@Repository` in `DebtsDAO` (additional details --> https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-repository-service). 3. Remove `@EntityScan(basePackages = "entity")` from `ServiceApplication`, as `@EnableAutoConfiguration` would do the trick (additional details --> https://www.baeldung.com/spring-entityscan-vs-componentscan).

Answer (score 0):

You are running your app from `x.y.z.ApplicationService` but your components are in different pacage like `x.y.a.YourComponent` which will NOT be picked up by the spring.

By default, spring scans package (and descendants) of your `@SpringApplication` class. In reference to the above it would be `x.y.z.*.....`

To solve your problem (alternatives)

1. Move your `ApplicationService` next to `DebtsApplication` so it will be "on top" of all required components (`@RestController` for example)
2. Add `@ComponentScan(basePackgages={'service.debts'})`
   to `ApplicationService` so you will "manually" show spring where to look for components.
3. There are other ways, but you should be fine with those 2